# Remove last characters in an elements text

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, slice

I'm looping through all elements with a specific class and want to remove the last characters. However, the code below doesn't work (i.e the slice code). What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.span-tag').each(function() {
    var tag = $(this).find('.tags');

    tag.text().slice(0,-4)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try in this way:

```
tag.text(tag.text().slice(0,-4))
```

you need to set the value of the text sliced

Comment: ah, never considered as a race :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
tag.text().slice(0,-4)
```

to

```
tag.text(tag.text().slice(0,-4));
```

your code becomes

```
$('.span-tag').each(function() {
    var tag = $(this).find('.tags');

    tag.text(tag.text().slice(0,-4));
}
```

`tag.text()` to get value

`tag.text(value)` to set value to tag element

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

The slice method returns a new array; it does not modify the array in-place.

You can do this:

```
$('.span-tag').each(function() {
    var tag = $(this).find('.tags');
    tag.text(tag.text().slice(0,-4));
}
```